# An English word (adj or verb) to describe your feeling when you did not do something you were expected to do

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an English word (adj or verb) to describe your feeling when you did not do something you were expected to do. For example:

> My friend's uncle has just passed away but I didn't say anything to him when I first heard the news because I was focusing on something else. Now looking back, I feel very bad about it. I should have said something. I feel ______________.

The word is pretty close to 'regret' but it's not 'regret'.

Comment: An example sentence with a blank space for the adjective or verb would be good.  Otherwise I think this question is too broad.

Comment: From just reading your question title, I was going to suggest "the joy of procrastination", but... your example was *way* darker than I was expecting.

Comment: -1  Your  example sentence does not match the description of the word request ("describe your feeling when you did not do something you were expected to do"). The "expected to do" part is vague; expected by who, why, when... Yourself, your inner voice,   your psyche, someone else  the universe? The question is unclear and the example sentence itself,  as it stands,  can be fitted with 100s of nouns.

Comment: Also, perhaps, *dismay* or *consternation*.

Comment: Why does 'regret' not work? We're not mind-readers - explain more how 'regret' would not be right.

Answer (score 19):

**Remorse** fits the bill.

From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remorse):

> a gnawing distress arising from a sense of guilt for past wrongs :  self-reproach

Oops - per Hank's suggestion: **remorseful**.

Comment: That's technically a noun but maybe **Remorseful**?

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to feel remorse, just as you can feel anger or happiness or any other emotion.

Answer (score 8):

The classic feeling of ***shame*** is perfect for what you are describing.

> shame (noun):   a painful feeling of humiliation or distress caused by the
>   consciousness of wrong or foolish behavior. ‘he felt a pang of shame at telling Alice a lie’ ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shame))

Also, **mortified** works here.

> mortification (noun): great embarrassment and shame. ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mortification))

e.g.  'When I thought back on how I handled the situation I was *mortified*.  And even today, I have a lingering feeling of *shame*.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that you are feeling **regretful** that you didn't do something you should have done.

> **re·gret·ful** (adj): feeling or showing regret ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regretful))

You also might be feeling **disappointed** in yourself and your actions.

> **dis·ap·point·ed** (adj): sad or displeased because someone or something has failed to fulfill one's hopes or expectations ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disappointed))

**Guilt-ridden** or **guilty** would also work, since you are feeling that you should have done something, but didn't.

> **guilt-rid·den** (adj): filled with feelings of guilt ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/guilt-ridden))
>   **guilt·y** (adj): culpable of or responsible for a specified wrongdoing ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guilty))

You may be **ashamed** that you did not do something that was expected of you.

> **a·shamed** (adj): embarrassed or guilty because of one's actions, characteristics, or associations ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ashamed))

A simple feeling **sorry** might also work in this context.

> **sor·ry** (adj): feeling regret or penitence ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sorry))

**Anguish** might also work if you are *really* upset about your action, but that option would lean toward a more extreme feeling.

> **an·guish**(v): be extremely distressed about something ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anguish))

Comment: Unlike with 100s of other words. The OP needs to clarify his question.

Answer (score 7):

Your first instinct was right.

"I **regret** not saying something sooner. I'm sorry for your loss."

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "guilt" is the right word here. Although "Regret" could also work, I think in the context of the definition given above, the word "regret" would jarr its use in other situations that could be defined by the same respective moraals. For example, you don't necessarily feel regret for something "you were expected to do", but you can feel a guilt for it, or evoke some other form of remorse.

Comment: I agree. Guilt is the appropriate answer here because it has the meaning closest to regret. Remorse is more inclined towards sadness of an event that occurred(death), rather than the repercussions of the event(inability to say anything before the death).

Answer (score 0):

Contrite. According to [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrite):

> feeling or showing sorrow and remorse for a sin or shortcoming
>
> - a contrite criminal
> - a contrite apology
> - contrite sighs

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/contrite):

> 1. caused by or showing sincere remorse.
> 2. filled with a sense of guilt and the desire for atonement; penitent: